# How do sudo environment variables work in linux?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm currently perplexed by the following:

```
sudo echo $MYVAR
```

outputs my variable from my .bashrc,

but

```
sudo ./test.sh
```

does not, where test.sh is the below executable:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $MYVAR
```

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04. Can someone enlighten me as to what's going on here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you run `sudo echo $MYVAR`, the environment variable is expanded in your shell ... before the `sudo` command gets to see it.

When you run a script using `sudo`, that script only sees the environment variables that `sudo` has included in the environment.  The default is to not to include them ... for security reasons.

The `sudo` command has an option `-E` that tells the command that the user wants to pass through all environment variables.  The sudoers configuration file may or may not permit this.